# Closing a lemma on list of nats

Tags: list, coq, nat, proof, induction

I am stuck to prove the following admitted lemma. Kindly help me how to proceed.

The function **sumoneseq** adds to and returns list of repetitions of 'true', in reverse order. Given [**true**;false;**true;true**;false;**true;true;true**], it returns [3;2;1]. The function **sumones** adds values in the nat list. Given [3;2;1], it returns 6.

```
Notation "x :: l" := (cons x l) (at level 60, right associativity).
Notation "[ ]" := nil.
Notation "[ x ; .. ; y ]" := (cons x .. (cons y nil) ..).


Fixpoint sumoneseq (lb: list bool) (ln: list nat) : list nat :=
 match lb, ln with
 | nil, 0::tl'' => tl''
 | nil, _ => ln
 | true::tl', nil => sumoneseq tl' (1::nil)
 | true::tl', h::tl'' => sumoneseq tl' (S h::tl'')
 | false::tl', 0::tl'' => sumoneseq tl' ln
 | false::tl', _ => sumoneseq tl' (0::ln)
 end.

Fixpoint sumones (ln: list nat) : nat :=
 match ln with
 | nil => 0
 | r::tl => r + (sumones tl)
 end. 

Lemma sumones_l: forall lb ln,  
 sumones (sumoneseq lb ln) = sumones ln + sumones (sumoneseq lb []).
Proof.
 induction ln.
 + simpl. auto.
 + simpl.  
 Admitted.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:

1. When proving a property of some function `f` using a direct induction, choose the parameter on which `f` is structurally recursive on. So in your example involving `sumoneseq`, induct on `lb` instead of `ln` since `sumoneseq` is structurally recursive on `lb`.
2. Proving a property of some function `f` where one or more of its arguments are fixed to specific values (e.g. `sumoneseq` with its second argument being `[]`) by direct induction is almost guaranteed to fail, since the value of that argument varies between recursive calls of `f`, meaning that you would not be able to apply the induction hypothesis in your inductive case. In that case, you need to manually generalize the induction hypothesis by finding a more general property on which `f` holds, with each of its arguments being sufficiently general. For example, instead of proving `forall lb ln, sumones (sumoneseq lb ln) = sumones ln + sumones (sumoneseq lb [])` directly by induction, try generalizing it to something like `forall lb ln ln', sumones (sumoneseq lb (ln ++ ln')) = sumones ln + sumones (sumoneseq lb ln')` instead and prove *that* by direct induction. Your desired result then follows as a corollary of that more general result.

You can learn more about generalizing the induction hypothesis in [James Wilcox's blog post](https://jamesrwilcox.com/InductionExercises.html) which generously includes 8 exercises of increasing difficulty on doing just that.

Now try to prove your lemma with these two points in mind. *Hint: when proving your more general statement about `sumoneseq` by direct induction, you may also find it helpful to extract out a suitable lemma on a certain property of `sumones`.*

If you've tried again to no avail then the full solution is provided below the horizontal rule (**spoiler alert!**).

---

Here goes the full solution. As you can probably see, a lot of case analysis is required on top of the main induction (likely due to your optimization in `sumoneseq` of discarding `0`s from `ln`) and the reasoning for many of these cases are actually very similar and repetitive. I could've probably further shortened the proof script with a bit of `Ltac` programming looking for similar patterns in the various cases but I haven't bothered doing so since I just hacked it up straight away.

```
From Coq Require Import List Lia.
Import ListNotations.

Fixpoint sumoneseq (lb: list bool) (ln: list nat)
  : list nat :=
  match lb, ln with
  | nil, 0::tl'' => tl''
  | nil, _ => ln
  | true::tl', nil => sumoneseq tl' (1::nil)
  | true::tl', h::tl'' => sumoneseq tl' (S h::tl'')
  | false::tl', 0::tl'' => sumoneseq tl' ln
  | false::tl', _ => sumoneseq tl' (0::ln)
  end.

Fixpoint sumones (ln: list nat) : nat :=
  match ln with
  | nil => 0
  | r::tl => r + (sumones tl)
  end.

Lemma sumones_app_plus_distr : forall l l',
  sumones (l ++ l') = sumones l + sumones l'.
Proof.
  induction l; simpl; intros; auto.
  rewrite IHl; lia.
Qed.

Lemma sumones_l' : forall lb ln ln',
  sumones (sumoneseq lb (ln ++ ln')) =
  sumones ln + sumones (sumoneseq lb ln').
Proof.
  induction lb; simpl; intros.
  - destruct ln, ln'; simpl; auto.
    + destruct n; rewrite app_nil_r; simpl; auto.
    + destruct n, n0; simpl; rewrite sumones_app_plus_distr;
        simpl; lia.
  - destruct a, ln, ln'; simpl; auto.
    + replace (S n :: ln ++ []) with ((S n :: ln) ++ [])
        by reflexivity.
      replace [1] with ([1] ++ []) by now rewrite app_nil_r.
      repeat rewrite IHlb; simpl; lia.
    + replace (S n :: ln ++ n0 :: ln')
        with ((S n :: ln ++ [n0]) ++ ln')
        by (simpl; now rewrite <- app_assoc).
      replace (S n0 :: ln') with ([S n0] ++ ln')
        by reflexivity.
      repeat rewrite IHlb.
      replace (S n :: ln ++ [n0])
        with ((S n :: ln) ++ [n0])
        by reflexivity.
      repeat rewrite sumones_app_plus_distr; simpl; lia.
    + destruct n.
      * replace (0 :: ln ++ []) with ((0 :: ln) ++ [])
          by reflexivity.
        replace [0] with ([0] ++ [])
          by now rewrite app_nil_r.
        repeat rewrite IHlb; simpl; lia.
      * replace (0 :: S n :: ln ++ [])
          with ((0 :: S n :: ln) ++ []) by reflexivity.
        replace [0] with ([0] ++ [])
          by now rewrite app_nil_r.
        repeat rewrite IHlb; simpl; lia.
    + destruct n, n0.
      * replace (0 :: ln ++ 0 :: ln')
          with ((0 :: ln ++ [0]) ++ ln')
          by (simpl; now rewrite <- app_assoc).
        replace (0 :: ln') with ([0] ++ ln') by reflexivity.
        repeat rewrite IHlb.
        repeat (repeat rewrite sumones_app_plus_distr;
          simpl); lia.
      * replace (0 :: ln ++ S n0 :: ln')
          with ((0 :: ln ++ [S n0]) ++ ln')
          by (simpl; now rewrite <- app_assoc).
        replace (0 :: S n0 :: ln') with ([0; S n0] ++ ln')
          by reflexivity.
        repeat rewrite IHlb.
        repeat (repeat rewrite sumones_app_plus_distr;
          simpl); lia.
      * replace (0 :: S n :: ln ++ 0 :: ln')
          with ((0 :: S n :: ln ++ [0]) ++ ln')
          by (simpl; now rewrite <- app_assoc).
        replace (0 :: ln') with ([0] ++ ln')
          by reflexivity.
        repeat rewrite IHlb.
        repeat (repeat rewrite sumones_app_plus_distr;
          simpl); lia.
      * replace (0 :: S n :: ln ++ S n0 :: ln')
          with ((0 :: S n :: ln ++ [S n0]) ++ ln')
          by (simpl; now rewrite <- app_assoc).
        replace (0 :: S n0 :: ln') with ([0; S n0] ++ ln')
          by reflexivity.
        repeat rewrite IHlb.
        repeat (repeat rewrite sumones_app_plus_distr;
          simpl); lia.
Qed.

Lemma sumones_l: forall lb ln,
  sumones (sumoneseq lb ln) =
  sumones ln + sumones (sumoneseq lb []).
Proof.
  intros; replace (sumoneseq lb ln)
    with (sumoneseq lb (ln ++ []))
    by (now rewrite app_nil_r); apply sumones_l'.
Qed.
```